# What is happening in below code of threading?

Tags: java, multithreading

Code:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyImlementThread mit = new MyImlementThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(mit);
        t.start();
        t = new Thread(mit);
        t.start();
    }
}


// MyImlementThread
class MyImlementThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("This is implemented run() method");
    }
}

/*
Output
This is implemented run() method
This is implemented run() method
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is the main thread starts two threads and exits. Each of the new threads writes a message to stdout, then ends. At that point since all the non-daemon threads have finished the JVM exits.

The posted code is confusing on account of it defining a Runnable but giving it a name ending in Thread.

A Thread object relates to an os-level thread, calling start on a Thread makes the code in the run method of the passed-in Runnable execute run on a separate thread from the one that called start.

The Runnable defines a task but doesn't specify how it runs. It could be passed into a specific Thread's constructor or submitted to an Executor or run by the current thread.

In this case the Runnable declared has no state, no instance variables are declared.  Here two threads can execute the same Runnable without a conflict because there is no shared state. The printstream that writes to the console is synchronized, so the lines written by the threads each get written one at a time and don't get jumbled together.